# PostgreSQL: How to create two instances in same window machine?

Tags: database, windows, instance, postgresql-9.1

I need to have additional instance for our production server.

Is it possible?

Where to begin?

Using Postgresql 9.1 on Windows Server

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, what i need is to run in windows. I don't know how to apply those instructions. :(

Comment: Are you sure you need a whole separate instance (on a separate port, with its own server configuration, transaction logs, etc.), and not just an additional database and/or tablespace in your existing instance?

Comment: yes, as much as possible separate port but same windows server. I need to have additional instance. Is that possible, @Wyzard?

Comment: Is Postgres already installed and you want to add another instance? Also 9.1 is no longer maintained (supported). You should **really** use an up-to-date version (9.5 or 9.6) if you are planning a new installation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Is Postgres already installed and you want to add another instance? YES. Currently downloading version 9.6.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you already have the binaries, then adding a second instance ("cluster") is done by running `initdb` and then registering that new instance as a Windows service.

(I will not prefix the name of the executables with the path they are stored in. You need to either add the `bin` directory of the Postgres installation to your system wide `PATH`, use fully qualified names, or simply change into the `bin` directory to make it the current directory)

To do that, open a command line (`cmd.exe`) and use `initdb` to create the instance:

```
initdb -D c:\Data\PostgresInstance2 -W -A md5
```

`-W` makes initdb prompt you for the name and password to be used as the superuser of that instance - make sure you remember the username and passwords you have given. `-D` specifies *where* the cluster should be created. Do **NOT** create that under `c:\Program Files`.

Once the instance (cluster) is initialized edit `c:\Data\PostgresInstance2\postgresql.conf` to use a different port, e.g. `port = 5433`. If the instance should be reachable from the outside you also need to adjust `listen_addresses`.

You can check if everything works by manually starting the new instance:

```
pg_ctl start -D c:\Data\PostgresInstance2
```

Once you have change the port (and adjusted other configuration parameters) you can create a Windows service for the new cluster:

```
pg_ctl register -N postgres2 -D c:\Data\PostgresInstance2
```

The service will execute with the "Local Network Account", so you **have** to make sure the privileges on the data directory are setup properly.

Comment: i cahnge conf port, but when i start server i get this msg
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Permission denied
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: Had same error as above, and realize I need to remove # which is a comment keyword, 
from #port = 5433 to port = 5433 , solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to create another PostgreSQL Instance on same windows server.

1. Stop the PostgreSQL Service
2. Point to PostgreSQL installation path (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL)
3. Go to File Explorer and copy the version to the same Postgres Folder.
   Ex: Copy Version 16 to 16-1
4. Open CMD as admin, navigate to folder 16-1 the BIN folder.
   EX:  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16-1\bin
5. Run below command
   pg_ctl register -N postgres16-1 -U "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16-1\data"
6. Navigate to data folder in 16-1 and then run below command to change the port number from 5432 to 5433.
   notepad postgresql.conf
7. Modify the PostMaster file as below
   notepad postmaster.opts
   C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/postgres.exe "-D" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data" to
   C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16-1/bin/postgres.exe "-D" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16-1\data"
8. You can find new postgres16-1 in services.msc.
   Before starting the service provide access to 16-1 folder with "NT Authority\Network Service" with full control.
9. Start the service 16-1 then connect using PGADMIN with new connection parameter as "LocalHost" and Post Nuber "5433"

That's it. You now successfully installed second postgreSQL Instance.

Happy Learning.

Answer (score 0):

@NewSheriff

Your start command for your second server needs to use the port you specified in config
e.g. if using port 5433 instead of port 5432
then adding:
-o "-p 5433"
to the end of your start-up command should get past the error message you mentioned